# Google Drive v3 API issue: Folders are not shown under root directory when use 'root' in parents in C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

I just wanted to see folders and files under root directory when i set ‘root’ in parents in Q, but I can see only one file titled “Get started” pdf file. (I used C# code)

Where are my folders?

But I can see folders when I search by name (ex. name=’Folder1′) in the code.
Also I can see the folder output when I use Api test called “Try this API” which is on API help website (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list).

So only C# code does not show folders?
Can you please tell me why it shows only files, not folders?

FYI: I authenticated using service account and used Google Drive v3 SDK

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack please dont open the same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

If the only file you are seeing is “Get started” pdf file that is a sure sign that you are using a service account for authentication.  Service accounts are not you. Think of it as a dummy user it has its own google drive account which by default has no files.

Either upload some files to it or share a directory with it on your personal drive account.

Comment: @DalmTo One question, each service account of one google account has its own drive?

Comment: Each service account you create in Google developer console has its on drive account yes.